# Chrome Extension: Manifest is not valid JSON. at line 22 Trailing comma not allowed

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

It gives me an error when trying to load my plugin -> `Manifest is not valid JSON. at line 22 Trailing comma not allowed`

manifest.json:

```
    {
    "name": "My First Plugin",
    "description" : "myfirstplugin",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["script.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "commands": {
    "smile_cmd": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+X"
      },
      "description": "Nothing"
    },
    "yell_cmd": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "windows": "Ctrl+Y"
      }
    },
}
```

When I remove a comma at the bottom, it then gives me `Manifest is not valid JSON. Syntax Error`

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove the comma at the second-to-last line and add another `}` at the end. Use any proper IDE that can format and validate JSON syntax or use an online validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wOxxOm said, but also make sure you having matching brackets.

```json
{
    "name": "My First Plugin",
    "description": "myfirstplugin",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "script.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "commands": {
        "smile_cmd": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+X"
            },
            "description": "Nothing"
        },
        "yell_cmd": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "windows": "Ctrl+Y"
            }
        }
    }
}
```